# How to animate cloth simulation (with thick fabric) in blender?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I wonder if there's any good ways to have cloth simulation on a dancing animation with something like a leather jacket on a character (with thickness using solidify modifier)?

Or a 2D mesh is a must...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so have you given your jacket a cloth simulation and does it work? this tutorial is rather good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg

Answer (score 1):

just increase cloth quality steps to 20, and bending, left is bending 0.5, right is bending 60, else default cloth settings

[image]

[image]